# interface id for ethernet card

Tags: linux, ethernet, ifconfig

My PC (CentOS)has one ethernet card 1, linked to the internal company network for internet surfing etc., and another ethernet card 2, linked with an embedded device for programming.

Each time, when I restart PC, I have ethernet card 1 active and ready (listed as "Eth0" by ifconfig command), and ethernet card 2 inactive (listed as "__tmp1835522531" by ifconfig command), waiting for configuration with some local ip address.

my question is:
why it is listed as "__tmp1835522531"?  Is it possible to make it listed as "Eth1", when PC restarts? How to do that?

Comment: Which distro are you running?

Answer (score 3):

try looking in /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules and match the mac address for the _tmp interface to an entry there (or make an entry if needed), then reboot.

Comment: unfortunately there is no such file "/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-cd.rules".

Comment: it is called 70-persistent-net.rules

Comment: unfortunately there is no such file either. I only have some file "60-net.rules", no "70-xxx" at all. Is there some problems with my kernel, or should I create such file myself?

Comment: sorry was a typo, is indeed -net.rules. If you have 60- try that one. in there it'll detail what everything gets called. iirc the number at the start is just used to decide what order the files in that dir get read in.

Comment: First, thanks for the follow-up. Unfortunately, guys (also including others), what the file "-net.rules" contains in my pc is as follows. ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", IMPORT{program}="/lib/udev/rename_device"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", RUN+="/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/net.hotplug", that is all, no rules found for any ethernet interfaces. So what should I do?

Comment: mine has some lines like this: SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:22:2a:35:3a:34", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

Answer (score 2):

1. insert an new rule to /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules with the mac adress of the tmp interface and name it eth1.  ( there should already be a similiar rule for eth0, take it as aa draft and just change the mac and the name to eth1 )
2. create the file to configure your interface: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1

Comment: HI, JMW, yes, I see ifcfg-eth0 there as follows. # Intel Corporation 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
HWADDR=B8:AC:6F:27:38:21
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet; but no ifcfg-eth1 file, so probably I need to create one as you said. But I did not find the mac address in this /etc/udev/rules.d/60-net.rules file. How should I add it.

Comment: you find out the address with ifconfig -a  ( for __tmp1835522531 you should see HWaddr )

Answer (score 2):

You might be subject to [this bug](http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=2791) or a similar.
You can try what JMW wrote or you can [run this script](http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=2791#c11018) which will basically
try install the kernel module again and reinstall it.
Finally there are several other scripts on that page, just be aware that it seems to be a kernel issue, thus whatever you try (if subject to this bug) will be a workaround.